# Finding local maxima using find_peaks

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, maxima

I am using `scipy.signal.find_peaks` in order to try and find the maximum values for very fluctuating data. Using the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
Data = [95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,229,444,457,387,280,188,236,181,183,183,185,186,189,190,190,190,179,165,151,151,161,214,213,213,214,213,212,195,179,160,158,155,114,98,164,346,229,39,134,149,194,1,153,171,187,185,104,102,100,90,90,92,92,92,93,93,93,93,93,93,94,94,94,94,94,11,1,11,11,70,182,104,58,60,134,115,99,97,99,98,98,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,93,93,152,206,221,286,326,341,360,377,391,392,393,393,393,394,406,418,420,422,422,408,389,345,329,276,224,166,113,-6,91,91,91,442,324,387,389,387,443,393,393,393,393,391,381,379,377,303,174,131,0,115,112,112,111,111,109,107,106,104,104,103,102,101,101,101,101,100,100,1,1,12,13,65,138,87]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Data)


#convert to 1D array
number_column = df.loc[:,'Data']
numbers = number_column.values

#finding peaks for 1D array
peaks = find_peaks(numbers, height = 300, threshold = 1, distance = 5)
height = peaks[1]['peak_heights'] #list of heights of peaks
peak_pos = numbers[peaks[0]]
print(peaks)

#plot the peaks
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.subplots()
ax.plot(numbers)
ax.scatter(peak_pos, height,color = 'r', s = 25, label = 'Maxima')
ax.legend
```

I am getting the local extrema of 457, 346, 442, 443. However this is a system where I need to get the following values as the extrema: (457, 346, 422, 443)

[image]

When plotting my extrema I am geting this:

[image]

So my question is does anyone know how to get the correct extrema I need? I am just missing that 422 value and have been playing around with the settings but have not been successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the line peak_pos = numbers[peaks[0]] to `peak_pos = peaks[0]` because peaks[0] gives you the index of the peaks which are the actual x coordinates you want to pass to `ax.scatter`.

To get the peak at 422, we can set the threshold to None (so that you aren't constraining yourself by vertical distance to the neighbors), and make the distance larger, such as 10.

Then you can add the heights as text annotations:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Data = [95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,229,444,457,387,280,188,236,181,183,183,185,186,189,190,190,190,179,165,151,151,161,214,213,213,214,213,212,195,179,160,158,155,114,98,164,346,229,39,134,149,194,1,153,171,187,185,104,102,100,90,90,92,92,92,93,93,93,93,93,93,94,94,94,94,94,11,1,11,11,70,182,104,58,60,134,115,99,97,99,98,98,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,96,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,94,93,93,152,206,221,286,326,341,360,377,391,392,393,393,393,394,406,418,420,422,422,408,389,345,329,276,224,166,113,-6,91,91,91,442,324,387,389,387,443,393,393,393,393,391,381,379,377,303,174,131,0,115,112,112,111,111,109,107,106,104,104,103,102,101,101,101,101,100,100,1,1,12,13,65,138,87]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':Data})

# convert to 1D array
number_column = df.loc[:,'Data']
numbers = number_column.values

#finding peaks for 1D array
# peaks = find_peaks(numbers, height = 300, threshold = 1, distance = 5)

peaks = find_peaks(numbers, height = 300, threshold = None, distance=10)
height = peaks[1]['peak_heights'] #list of heights of peaks
peak_pos = peaks[0]
print(peaks)

# plot the peaks
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.subplots()
ax.plot(numbers)
ax.scatter(peak_pos, height,color = 'r', s = 25, label = 'Maxima')
ax.legend

## add numbers as text annotations
for i, text in enumerate(height):
    if text.is_integer():
        ax.annotate(int(text), (peak_pos[i], height[i]), size=10)
    else:
        ax.annotate(text, (peak_pos[i], height[i]), size=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, this solved my problem of the position, and great input to add the text! I was wondering if you had any idea how to solve the other problem, I have been playing around with the paramets but that 442 peak should not be showing up and instead should be 422 which is the max of the "hump" peak before it

Comment: Oh I missed that. I'll check the documentation and see if any of the arguments can help: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question to be more accurate after taking your labeling results. I have been messing around with different settings from that sheet but have not been successful

Comment: @SeanK22 you can set the `threshold=None` and `distance=10` and you'll get the desired output. i have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Derek! I have marked your solution as correct, thanks for the help.